# Ensure the most up-to-date value from an AWS database service

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am building a simple service for a mobile application that requires persistence in AWS. The most important thing for me is to ensure that mobile applications always retrieve the most recent value, e.g. if I write value **V** in row **R** and then read from **R** then I will always get **V**.

I looked at some NoSQL services like DynamoDB and I believe that I cannot get this guarantee, especially because we are talking about eventual consistency databases.

On the other hand I was expecting to have this guarantee provided by one of the RDS services of AWS, e.g. Aurora MySQL, but according to [this link](https://developer.rackspace.com/blog/Understanding-Amazon-Aurora-Endpoints/) it may not be the case. It does make sense that this is not provided by a fully consistent service if we consider that a write request may be placed in node **A** and the subsequent read request placed in node **B**, before **A** updates **B**.

It is said that this can be achieved if we redirect our read requests to the same node in which we performed the write ones, but then again I think this should be quite inefficient and we can achieve the same result using a NoSQL database, correct?

Therefore my question is: is there an AWS service capable of providing this guarantee?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

DynamoDB will give you this guarantee, provided that you explicitly request a strongly-consistent read. See [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html).

The link that you provided for Aurora is relevant to any RDBMS architecture in which you write to a master but read from a replica. This happens in Aurora, RDS, and any other database system that performs asynchonous replication. You can achieve read-after-write consistency by writing *and* reading from the master endpoint.

Comment: Thank you, which of the two options is likely to perform better? i) Dynamo with strongly-consistent read or ii) RDS with write and read from the master endpoint?

Comment: That is entirely dependent on your data architecture, usage patterns, and how much you're willing to pay.